# Ruby on Rails showing truncated date for each date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am using RoR with MSSQL server as database, in a table I am saving date with '**date**' datatype.

RoR saving the date correctly e.g if I am saving 2012-10-20 then it is saving 2012-10-20 but when I display it on front-hand it display like 2012-10-02 for 2013-10-20, 2012-10-01 for 2013-10-10, 2012-10-01 for 2013-10-15 etc.

What is going wrong... I can't figure it out

**Edit**

I am not asking for date formating technique. The issue is that date not fetched correctly as it saved in database, if I used datatime datatype instead of date datatype then all goes right.

Comment: Is this a view problem or is the database (adapter) returning a wrong  date? What does `User.last.created_at` return in `rails console`?

Comment: It is database(adapter) problem which returning wrong date in RoR. It always return truncated date like 2012-10-01 for 2012-10-15

Comment: which version of rails are you using and which database adapter gem? Sounds like a bug with the adapter

Comment: Using rails 3.2.13 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
<%= @user.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
```

Or if you want it to be more readable then:

```
<%= @user.created_at.to_date %>
```

You can try both which ever you like

**EDIT**

You have to do like mentioned above otherwise you have to create a new attribute to store date only. `created_at` is default `timestamp` type [See this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column). You can use any of both ways either convert `created_at` to `date` or introduce new `column` to `table`

Comment: I am already storing date only in table but the issue is database returning wrong date like 2012-10-01 for 2012-10-15

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying it on your view?

For example the following would show "January 2010"

```
<%= @user.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") %>
```

You probably want year, month, date? So %Y %m %d

Comment: <%= @user.created_at %> this the format I am using. I don't want year, month or day just straight date like 2012-12-15

Answer (score 0):

According to the [github page](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) of the adapter:

> **Date/Time Data Type Hinting**
>
> SQL Server 2005 does not include a native data type for just date or
>   time, it only has datetime. To pass the ActiveRecord tests we
>   implemented two simple class methods that can teach your models to
>   coerce column information to be cast correctly. Simply pass a list of
>   symbols to either the coerce_sqlserver_date or coerce_sqlserver_time
>   methods that correspond to 'datetime' columns that need to be cast
>   correctly.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  coerce_sqlserver_date :last_read
  coerce_sqlserver_time :bonus_time
end
```

This should point you in the right direction

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2